# Convert curl to ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

Simple question: is there any way to convert this curl to an ajax request?

```
curl -v https://api.mydomain.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

While I'm quite sure about what to do with `-H`, I've no idea of how to specify `-u` and `-d`.

Answer (score 5):

If you use [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) you can use `setRequestHeader` for setting request headers (-H)

`-u` can be done by simple prepending the credentials to the url:
`https://1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF@api.mydomain.com/v1/oauth2/token`

`-d` is the POST body which should be the first argument in `.send(body)`

Comment: I have the same problem, only difference is an "-X", how do I do it?

Comment: You need to something else than GET? Its the first argument in the .open function...

Answer (score 1):

This should be a valid example using the jQuery Ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.mydomain.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"grant_type": "client_credentials"},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [anylib].base64encode('1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF'));
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en_US');
    }
});
```

Edit - Native: (be aware of different browser implementation)

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
        consolelog(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + [anylib].base64encode('1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF'));
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en_US');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xhr.open("POST","https://api.mydomain.com/v1/oauth2/token",true);
xhr.send("grant_type=client_credentials");
```

Edit2: Just got told by a colleague you need to base64 encrypt your auth here.

Comment: I was looking for a vanilla JS solution, but thanks anyway   :-)

Comment: Here we go, added a native js version ;)

Comment: `setRequestHeader` function can only be called _after_ `xhr.open`.